# socket.io, using PHP session as socket.id with redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

I'm developing an online, text-based RPG ([Github](https://github.com/Froz89/SoD)); currently I've a PHP backend that stores session data in a redis server. For everything where real-time comunication is needed (chat, messaging and the list of connected users) I use Node.js and socket.io for websockets.

I have currently 3 namespaces on my websocket server:

1. Messaging Server
2. Online Server
3. Chat Server

I've made it work, but I'm afraid that most of it is made off of "hacking". Right now I've problems to send a message to a specific client. For example, if I'm writing a private message to another user, when I click "send" I want the following logic.

1. User is writing his message, when he clicks on "send" the client emits to the websocket server something like `{"sender": 15, "message": "blablabla", "receiver": 17};`
2. On the websocket server, the server gets the event and from there I must align the "receiver" with the client session. At every connection to a namespace I add to the socket object two properties, accountId and accountName that are results of my Auth module.

   `/* POSTA SERVER */
   postaServer.on('connection', function postaConnect(socket) {
       var phpSessId = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie)
           .PHPSESSID;
       if (phpSessId === undefined || phpSessId === '') {
           console.log('Sessione non trovata');
           socket.disconnect();
       } else {
           // modulo socket_auth
           checkSession(phpSessId, function (auth) {
               if (auth) {
                   // Auth retrieves account id and account name from redis
                   socket.accountId = auth.id;
                   socket.accountName = auth.nome;
                   socket.emit('serverMessage', 'connesso al server di posta');
                   var conn = mysql.createConnection(DB);
                   getMessaggiPosta(socket.accountId, conn, function (err, result) {
                       if (err) {
                           console.log(err);
                       } else {
                           socket.emit('refreshPosta', result);
                       }
                   });
               } else {
                   socket.disconnect();
               }
           });
       }
   });`

How can I emit an event only to a specific client without the use of the built-in socket.id?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the module "socket-io-emitter" for node.

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({
  host: redisHost,
  port: redisPort
});
```

And then emit to a certain user via a user specific key:

```
io.to('myKey' + '_user_' + userId).emit('myEvent', {
  data: 'hello'
});
```